# discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'Member' object has no attribute 'avatar_url_as'

Tags: discord.py

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import datetime
import asyncio
import random
from config import settings

from PIL import Image
from io import BytesIO


client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = settings['PREFIX'], intents=discord.Intents.all())
client.remove_command('help')

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    # status_task.start()
    print('Ready')

@client.command()
async def wanted(ctx, user: discord.Member = None):
    if user == None:
        user = ctx.author
        
    wanted = Image.open('tester.jpg')

    asset = ctx.author.avatar_url_as(size = 128)
    data = BytesIO(await asset.read())
    pfp = Image.opem(data)

    pfp = pfp.resize((177,177))

    wanted.paste(pfp, (120,212))

    wanted.save("profile.jpg")

    await ctx.send(file = discord.File("profile.jpg"))
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Астик\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 360, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\Астик\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 927, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Астик\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 190, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'Member' object has no attribute 'avatar_url_as'
```

What am I doing wrong?
I've tried many things but it didn't work, please help...

I reinstalled the libraries, it did not help, I did not find an answer on the Internet (Translator)

Answer (score 0):

You're using the wrong attribute. You want to use either `ctx.author.avatar` or `ctx.author.display_avatar`.

You can see the docs for that [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Member). Either one of those will return an [`Asset`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Asset) object which fits with the rest of your code.

Comment: AttributeError: 'Context' object has no attribute 'avatar'

Comment: I made a typo. It's `ctx.author.display_avatar`. But that's in docs so make sure to _actually_ check them out.

Comment: teError: 'Member' object has no attribute 'display_avatar'

Comment: Okay, and did you try `ctx.author.avatar`?

Comment: discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Comment: Okay... what did you try? how did your code change? Posting _just_ an error message isn't very helpful. You're probably trying to treat a string like a function - hence the error.

Comment: I want to make the bot put the user's avatar in the picture: https://i.pinimg.com/736x/45/95/10/459510f67944502502bbbff50f5ca59a--best-templates-poster-templates.jpg

Comment: Okay - but I can't help with your error message unless you show the code that got you that error message. Using `ctx.author.avatar` should work - but you're getting an error without showing the code that _gives_ the error.